# Blender Scaling, Sizes

Tags: python, blender

Im trying to design a piece for a mechanism in Blender, its x and y coordinates size should be equal. The z coordinate(height) should be a little higher.
The size which is getting shown in my measurments is different.
[image]
The Scale is corresponding to the shown lenghts and heights, 1.6 and 1.2.
But why does it say in dimensions that X is different than y when they clearly are equally big.

Comment: You have selected other object, it is not yellow/orange (active), maybe?

Comment: Nope, the correct one is selected. 
Is this weird behaviour?